# Rails takes extremely slow time to process ajax json

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It takes my rails app an insane amount time to server ajax request. This is my test code

```
def test
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: '{"text" : "simpleJson"}' }
  end
end
```

base on server log, it take my apps only 1ms to execute request :

[image]

but in browser, it is always recieved response in about 20k+ ms

[image]

When i change the json return to nothing ( `format.json { render json: {} }` ) the request only takes ~18ms. So I guess rails has some trouble when sending json back to client (because server log say the method test execute very fast). But I'm not sure about that because I'm very new to ruby and rails. My localhost is run by puma 3.10.0.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I guess thats not the valid JSON. Try `render json: {"text" : "simpleJson"}`

Comment: maybe not related to your question, but why not `GET` in this case?

Comment: @Pavan It will cause syntax error if you use `render json: {"text" : "simpleJson"}`



@kaspertine I dont know why, but if i define get 'books/test' in my routes.rb and call a get ajax, it will be route to the method get book by id, in this case, "test" will become the id

Comment: I think not.Did you get error?

Comment: @Pavan ruby throw [this error](https://i.imgur.com/zvCNniK.png) , I'm sure my code is a valid json string, becuase firefox dosen't complain about the response, if I use `render json: '{text : "simpleJson"}'` , it will complain me in the response.

Comment: @hai_uit The `respond_to` block is excees here, remove it. The `render json: {}` wait a ruby object, to convert it to json, not a string with json. @Pavan the whitespace after hash key is not allowed, this `{"text" : "simpleJson"}` is a wrong syntax, here is right `{"text": "simpleJson"}`

Comment: @Зелёный Yep the whitespace!

Comment: remove the white space make the syntax correct, but remove response_to doesn't solve the problem. I don't think my problem come from invalid json object, because I met it the first time with a json object created by ajax-datatables-rails gem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change from puma server to webrick solve my issue, but after doing some google  the root cause of my problem maybe  because I run rails on Window Subsystem Linux. At the moment, puma is slow in WSL.